# error: (-215:Assertion failed) inv_scale_x > 0 in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, opencv

I am receiving this error when running this code:

```py
import cv2
import torch
from tracker import *
import numpy as np
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\MSI\\Desktop\\yolov5vehiclecount\\test.mp4')


def POINTS(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE :  
        colorsBGR = [x, y]
        print(colorsBGR)
        

cv2.namedWindow('FRAME')
cv2.setMouseCallback('FRAME', POINTS)

tracker = Tracker()
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    frame=cv2.resize(frame, None,(1020,500))
    
    # we are going to use a panda method
    results =model(frame)
    frame=np.squeeze(results.render())
    cv2.imshow('FRAME',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==27:
        break
cap.release()
```

**Error:**

```
    frame=cv2.resize(frame, None,(1020,500))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4065: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inv_scale_x > 0 in function 'cv::resize'
```

Comment: complete traceback is always a good idea. -- @TheCodingPenguin this question had nothing to do with yolo. that was entirely secondary.

Answer (score 1):

First, [look at the documentation of `cv::resize()` and `cv.resize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)

[image: don't even have to click the link]

The signatures for C++ and Python are ***not identical***.

In Python, the second parameter is the `dsize`. You passed `None` for that, probably thinking that it would be the `dst` parameter.

Passing `None` for `dsize` <s>is not allowed</s> *requires passing other parameters to make up for it, but those weren't there either*. That is why the exception occurred.

Comment: "Passing None for dsize is not allowed." -- it is, but then you have to provide non-zero values for the optional `fx` and `fy` arguments.

Comment: From docs: "`dsize` -- output image size; if it equals zero (`None` in Python), it is computed as .... Either `dsize` or both `fx` and `fy` must be non-zero. "

Comment: a valid point :)